# Helper class: Static or non-static functions

Tags: php

When creating a helper class that has methods like stripping whitespace from a string, do you create the methods as `static` or non-`static` functions?

Also if the static method wants to call another function `do_magic()` in the class, how should the function be defined as (static or non-static?) and do we have to use `self::`?

```
class Helper {
    public static strip_whitespace() {
        // do some magic
        self::do_magic();

    }

    private do_magic() {
        // magic
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd assume that, as with most OOP languages, you can't call an instance from a static context. It would just not make sense.

Comment: I think this is a hard question to answer without knowing the full sope of what you're attempting to design.

Comment: This might be better suited for [programmers.SE]

Comment: @BOMEz Its just a general purpose helper class where a method `strip_whitespace()` in the class will call on another method `do_magic()` in the class.

Comment: @J.Steen that's why I said might! Because I think it's off topic here

Comment: Is do_magic() going to be called on its own as well, or only by strip_whitespace?

Comment: @DiMono It will only be called by `strip_whitespace()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make both of them static. Static methods are for functions that don't rely on an instance of the class being created, and that's what you seem to be doing here.

```
class Helper {
    public static strip_whitespace($string) {
        // do some magic
        return self::do_magic();

    }

    private static do_magic() {
        // return magic
    }
}

$result = Helper::strip_whitespace("  I'm a string!  ");
```

Comment: Is using static methods a normal way of creating such general purpose helper classes? I looked into a few classes (for specific purposes) created by others and they dont use `self::` but `$this->` instead which requires creating the object.

Comment: Yep. It sure it. Edit: it depends how you want to go. The advantage to using instantiated classes is that they'll hold on to values for you for later use. If you have no need for that, then static functions are fine

Comment: Also of note: non-static functions can call static functions using self::functionname()